# Is it possible to create an incremental array?

Tags: scripting, modifiers

The effect I am trying to achieve is an array that is fully editable in one instance, with Text labels incrementing in value, i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. Is this possible? I know by nature it is not possible by using the *Array* modifier, but is there some workaround?

The sort of result I am going for is like this:

[image: Incremental Array]

What I was thinking is making a script to duplicate like with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and shove a count value into the Text element of the duplicated group.

### Some things I am looking for/implementation suggestions:

- Editable offset
- Duplicates editable text element
- Use a count variable to set the value of the text element
- Make it expandable
- Start from 1, go to at least 32 (non-limited is best)
- Honesty as to the difficulty to create this feature

Comment: is it possible to use one text object? if no should they always be linked?

Comment: @Chebhou They should always be linked, as in changes to one affect all the others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go!

Keywords: Number Array Watch Dial

[image]

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import IntProperty,FloatProperty

class NumberArray(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add a simple box mesh"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_number_array"
    bl_label = "Add Number Array"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    start = IntProperty(name="Start",description="Start value",min=0, max=100,default=1 )
    count = IntProperty(name="Count",description="Number of items to create",min=1, max=100, default=1  )
    offset = FloatProperty(name="Offset",description="Distance",min=0.01, max=100.0, default=1.0 )

    def execute(self, context):
        x = 0.0
        pos = self.start
        end = self.count + self.start
        print(context)
        while pos < end:
            bpy.ops.object.text_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(x, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
            ob=bpy.context.object
            ob.data.body = str(pos)
            x = x + self.offset
            pos = pos +1
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(NumberArray.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NumberArray)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NumberArray)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Updated (works with 2.74):

[image]
https://github.com/3dbug/blender

[image]

Run the script in *Object Mode* by *Add / Curve / Create Dials and Scales*.

Comment: This is awesome!! You're the man! Can I edit one text object and have the changes reflected across them all (i.e. font changes)?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Thanks, I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: Changing the font doesn't appear to work, however I found a workaround. Select all, make the first active, and press `L` *> Fonts*. Works brilliantly!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise The 2nd version of the script allows you to select from already loaded fonts.

Comment: @stacker I turned that into [an addon in my collection](https://github.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/blob/master/numberArray.py), I added a few lines to get around the errors of no fonts existing. I also moved it to add curve as that is more accurate than a mesh object.

Comment: @sambler cool, I already extended it to create speedometers and stuff, should I fork your project on git and commit it?

Comment: @stacker that repo is the contrib addons with extras I have added so you might be better off with it in your own addon collection repo. I can always merge in other changes you make if I know your repo.

Comment: I get an error in 2.74, can you fix that?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise This takes some time, I will try to fix it over the weekend

Comment: @stacker Ok, I don't need it right off, I have other things I can work on instead for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Does not work on macos 12.4. Blender version used 2.8. Probably the pyton version. I need to generate 10000 objects 1, 2, 3 .... 100000. That is with a difference of +1. Could you help?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/154845)